# Calling PHP in jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

I have a site where you click on a product name and it launches a URL with a filter and it returns forum posts relevant to that product name:

E.g. www.google.com/product?=blah

Instead of having to navigate to this URL is it possible to launch it in a DIV dynamically rather than the user having to click a link. Looking to develop a dashboard type view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its easy :)

```
$.get('ajax/test.html', function(data) {
  $('.result').html(data);
  alert('Load was performed.');
});
```

see more here http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/

Answer (score 1):

You need [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/). You can use JQuery to perform AJAX queries to a PHP website.